# display 0 to 23 hours table using php or mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql that has time date and in military format ( 2014-01-22 16:10:02 )

**caller_data**

```
|ID | caller_id   |       call_time      
| 1 | 123         | 2014-01-22 16:10:02          
| 2 | 123         | 2014-01-22 16:30:02          
| 3 | 123         | 2014-01-22 17:10:02          
| 4 | 123         | 2014-01-22 18:05:45
```

on the range of their time like 16:10 and 16:30 . I group them using HOUR(), the result is 16. I will count it of how many times did the caller call on the range of that hour. so that would be 2.
My query:

```
SELECT caller_id,
HOUR(str_to_date(date_stamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s")) as hourly,
count(*) as total
from caller_data
group by hourly
order by hourly;
```

which the result should be:

```
caller_id    |  hourly |   total  
 123         |   16    |    2   
 123         |   17    |    1 
 123         |   18    |    1
```

I want to display these 3 rows on a 0-23 . I've been trying to display this with php but it display 3 times when I created a for $i <= 23 ..

```
for($i=0;i<=23;$i++)
{
   foreach ($rec as $row):
       echo $row['hourly'];
       echo $row['caller_id'];
       echo $row['total'];
   endforeach;
}
```

I dont know if it's possible to display this on mysql.. can someone show how to do it with php or mysql?

```
| hours | caller_id   | total 
| 0     | 123         |  0
| 1     | 123         |  0        
| 2     | 123         |  0       
| 3     | 123         |  0     
| 4     | 123         |  0
| 5     | 123         |  0
| 6     | 123         |  0        
| 7     | 123         |  0       
| 8     | 123         |  0     
| 9     | 123         |  0
| 10    | 123         |  0
| 11    | 123         |  0
| 12    | 123         |  0        
| 13    | 123         |  0       
| 14    | 123         |  0     
| 15    | 123         |  0
| 16    | 123         |  2        
| 17    | 123         |  1       
| 18    | 123         |  1     
| 19    | 123         |  0
| 20    | 123         |  0
| 21    | 123         |  0     
| 22    | 123         |  0
| 23    | 123         |  0
```

Comment: Do it on php side. Using `for`

Comment: Yes I've done that. I will display my code.

Comment: fetch it into a php array with hour as a key and the whole row as a value then iterate `$i` using `for` checking if a particular hour presents or not

Comment: uhmmmm @zerkms can you display some pseudo code for that. Sorry Im really slow in understanding .

Comment: assuming you have the result set that you currently have and a piece of paper. How would you do it manually?

Comment: @Vincent You'll never become a real programmer if you expect to get things like this spoon-fed to you. You learn to program by working things like this out. When you read each row from the database, get its hour, than put it into an array whose key is the hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in SQL with a `left outer join`.  You just have to type in all the hours:

```
select caller_id, n.n as hourly, coalesce(total, 0) as total
from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
      select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all
      select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12 union all
      select 13 union all select 14 union all select 15 union all select 16 union all
      select 17 union all select 18 union all select 19 union all select 20 union all
      select 21 union all select 22 union all select 23 union all select 24
     ) n left outer join
     (select caller_id, HOUR(str_to_date(date_stamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s")) as hourly,
             count(*) as total
      from caller_data
      group by hourly
     ) rep
     on n.n = rep.hourly
order by hourly;
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that doing that in php would be 10 times more maintainable :-)